# Non-commutative symplectic geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry

How is non-commutative symplectic geometry defined? How does it differ from symplectic geometry? Does Darboux's theorem apply also there?

Comment: Do you have a reference for non-commutative symplectic geometry? I've never heard of this, and am curious.

Comment: I am not exactly sure whether this is actually what I mean: http://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/Formal%20non-commutative%20symplectic%20geometry.pdf